# Consume external web service in Magento/PHP

Tags: php, magento, soap, magento-1.5

Are there any tutorials or good examples of how I can utilize (consume?) an external web service via SOAP from within Magento? (Magento is a PHP based software system)

I see TONS of tutorials on accessing Magento data externally using SOAP and Magento's API, but I want to access an *external* web service from *within* Magento.

I've done a bit of research and I have to imagine I can use the SoapClient class to do this, but I'm not sure how the required keys and method calls translate to setting up/using the SoapClient class.  If someone can point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it!

### Here's an example

Let's say I need to send the following SOAP request to **http://someurl.somewhere.com**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://api.channeladvisor.com/webservices/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <web:APICredentials>
            <web:DeveloperKey>DeveloperKey</web:DeveloperKey>
            <web:Password>Password</web:Password>
        </web:APICredentials>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <web:RequestAccess>
            <web:localID>99999999</web:localID>
        </web:RequestAccess>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How would I go about doing this in Magento?

Comment: I'm actually using __Zend_Soap_Client__ rather than __SoapClient__, but still no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Magento is a php application based on  zend framework so any tutorial that is about zend and soap will also do. You can do any php related stuff in any magento file (exept from config files) although the best place to do such request are models.

Comment: I've been reading every tutorial I can find but I still can't get this to work.  I downloaded soapUI4.0.0 and I am able to do everything I want through there but it still doesn't work from my Magento store through PHP.  Perhaps I don't understand SOAP well enough or how to use the Zend_Soap_Client in Magento.  Either way, I'm stuck.  Someone please help!